# How do I get the value from a NumericUpDown

Tags: c#

I have a `NumericUpDown` in my form.
And I want use its value here: `Thread.Sleep(ValueInNumericUpDown)`
How do I get the value?

Comment: Latif, as a new user you may have more luck if you follow this guide when writing questions: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Okay, thanks. I'm going to take a look.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
int count = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Round(numericUpDown1.Value, 0));
Thread.Sleep(count )
```

Comment: Thanks, I know it's a very easy question. But this helped me a lot.

Comment: What's the easier way? Please share it.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at your C# documentation for the NumericUpDown control.  Simply get it's value and pass it as an argument to the sleep method.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.numericupdown.value(v=vs.110).aspx